# Save edits as Project in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, save

This [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/customize-how-you-save-edits.htm) suggests that you can saves edits (Currently Editor -> Save Edits) as the same time as a project.

Is it still possible to do something similar, change the option(s) so it saves edits AND the project using ArcMap?

Comment: I don't think you can, since they have different functions. But someone else might know differently? However, what you can do is to go into Customize mode (Customize menu) and add the Save Edits button to a more easily accessible spot, maybe right next to the Save project button? That's what I have done at least :)

Comment: BTW, the link you refer to is for ArcGIS Pro, which is not the same as ArcMap (as you have tagged your question). It's not really a matter of versions (although Pro came with 10.3), but rather that they are two different programs.

Comment: That explains that. I assumed that ArcGIS pro was an updated renamed version of ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ArcGIS 10.x for Desktop architecture while that documentation is for ArcGIS Pro.

Consequently, for the ArcMap application, you will need to manually Save Edits.